# Java Arraylist reinitialize

Tags: java, arraylist

So what I'm trying to do is to add an array of strings to my Arraylist BDDvars.
The issue I seem to be facing is that after adding 'temp' (which is an array of strings) to the BDDvars list, when I instantly print -- I get values. However, after reinitializing temp, somehow the values that were present in my arraylist are also reset. Would appreciate some help on why this is happening. Thanks!

Code is here:

```
    List<String[]> BDDvars =new ArrayList<String[]>();

    BDDvars.add(temp);
    System.out.println(BDDvars.get(0)[0]); // this gives value of temp
    for(int n =0;n<11;n++)
      temp[n] = "";
    System.out.println(BDDvars.get(0)[0]); // this gives empty string - why?
```

Comment: Can we see the code in the add method please?

Comment: You added a _reference_ to the array, not a copy of the array.

Comment: Sorry could you see what I've edited and see if you can understand the question better? Thanks

Comment: replace your for loop with  temp = null; this is simple and you are not messing with reference added to BDDvars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `temp` to `BDDvars` you're not creating a new array. Instead both temp and an element in `BDDvars` are using the same reference.

Make a copy of the array first if you want to modify temp without modifying the value in `BDDvars`:

```
String[] tempCopy = new String[temp.length];
System.arraycopy( temp, 0, tempCopy, 0, temp.length);
BDDvars.add(tempCopy);
```

**EDIT**

or use `clone`

```
BDDvars.add(temp.clone());
```

Comment: You might as well use `.clone()` or `Arrays.copyOf` rather than doing the `System.arraycopy` yourself.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yup, i over-thought that one haha

Comment: Excellent. This is what I wanted. Thanks for the prompt response!